# Checkbox module, how to save, edit, and update. (Beginner)

Tags: php, mysql, post

This is my HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Jaywalking" /> 
Jaywalking<br>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Littering" /> 
Littering<br>


                        <input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Vendor" /> 
Illegal Vendor
```

This is my PHP code

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox'];

mysql_query("insert into tblcitizen(violation) values ('$violation')",$conn) or die (mysql_error());
```

How can i update this checkbox? for example, i choose the jaywalking in my registration form, and i want to edit it, what do i need to do if i want it to be checked if i fetch it? please give a sample code. thank you much appreciated.

Comment: No one is sitting here to give you sample code. First Try yourself & google then Stackoverflow

Comment: Considering you are a beginner , my advise would be to separately try individual items 1) Retrieve value of single checkbox 2) Retrieve value of a checkbox from multiple checkboxes 3) MySQL SELECT 4) MySQL INSERT 5) MySQL UPDATE , etc . You can google and find plenty of examples on these . Once you are able to do these individually , you can try accomplishing what you have asked in your question . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have another table related to `tblcitizen` as ManyToOne, so that you be able to create separate record for each submitted checkbox with the Id of the checkbox as value, then you will be able to update each record separately.

If you want to keep it in one table and save all value in one field separated by a delimiter and if the checkbox is not checked the value will not be save; for example if we have 3 checkboxes with these values *jaywalking, littering, mysample* and first, third ones are checked the value which is saved in Database should be `jaywalking,mysample`.
I assume this is your form on edit mode:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tblcitizen` WHERE `id`='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$selected_boxes = explode(',', $row['violation']);
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Jaywalking" <?php in_array('Jaywalking', $selected_boxes) ? 'checked' : '' ?> /> Jaywalking<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Littering" <?php in_array('Littering', $selected_boxes) ? 'checked' : '' ?> /> Littering<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Vendor" <?php in_array('Illegal Vendor', $selected_boxes) ? 'checked' : '' ?> /> Illegal Vendor
```

Now to edit after submit

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox'];
$query = "UPDATE `tblcitizen` SET `tblcitizen` = '$violation' WHERE `id`='$id'";
...
```

This is the simplest way to implement this logic

Comment: i'll just copy paste what you have been code sir, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not just paste, you need to some modification base on your code, my code is just a sample. You're welcome Sir :)

Comment: base on my code sir, what is the $current_value and $submitted_index sir?

Comment: `$current_value` is the value of `violation` in your table which you select first. `$submitted_index` is the index of the specific checkbox which you want to edit, for example if you want to edit the second checkbox it can be 2

Comment: thank you sir, i understand the current_value but what is submitted_index is it the 'jaywalking', 'littering', illegal vendor' ?

Comment: Sorry it was time to sleep here, anyway; yes it is. I got another suggestoin, why don't you save the values as a single value separated by comma (e.g `jaywalking,littering`. I edit my solution might help you better